# Get total amount of visitor count to website PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

Assignment for uni. As part of it I have to get the total number of visitors to the website and also the total number of unique visitors to the website. I have got the unique visitor count using IP addresses and storing them in a DB. How would I get the total amount of visitors? Need this:

Total amount of visitors = X
Unique = X

This is the code for getting unique visitors:
Thanks in advance.

```
try {
$DBH=new pdo("mysql:host=$webserver;dbname=$db", $user,$password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Not connected".$e->getMessage();
}

//get IP
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//check if the ip address already exists in DB
$query1 = "SELECT IP FROM counter WHERE IP='$ipAddress'"; 
$check = $DBH->prepare($query1);
$check->execute();
$checkIP=$check->rowCount();
if ($checkIP==0) {
$query2 = "INSERT INTO counter(IP) VALUES('$ipAddress')";
$insertIP=$DBH->prepare($query2);
$insertIP->execute();
}

$number=$DBH->prepare("SELECT IP FROM counter");
$number->execute();
$visitor=$number->rowCount();


?>
```

Comment: Add a count column to the table and then use an Insert/Update statement to either increase the count of an existing IP or add the new IP with count 1 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Why prepare and execute a query that you aren't using parameters properly on? You leave yourself vulnerable **and** make your code slower. Use proper parameterized queries where you have variables, just use query directly where you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Everything: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...

Unique: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field) FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

You can group visitors by IP and have the number of visits for each one and also the number of uniq visitors via `$visitor = $check->rowCount();`

```
SELECT IP, count(*) as nb FROM counter WHERE IP='$ipAddress' GROUP BY IP
```

Then you can have the sum with

```
$results = $check->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
$visitors = array_sum($results);
```